# html form with javascript window.location not working

Tags: javascript, html

I added this code to my website:

```
<script>
function checkPassword(name, pwd) {
    if (name == "jamie") {
        if (pwd == "198237645") {
            window.location = "member.html"
        } else {
            document.write("Wrong Password!")
        }
    } else {
        document.write("Wrong Name!")
    }
}
</script>
<form action="">
  Login Name : <input type="text" name="loginname"><br>
  Login Pwd : <input type="password" name="loginpwd"><br>
  <input type="submit" onclick="checkPassword(this.form.loginname.value,this.form.loginpwd.value)" value="Login">
</form>
```

However, after i inserted the correct password & name, i only see the link became:

```
http://tool-box.weebly.com/test.html?loginname=jamie&loginpwd=198237645
```

What should i do? if i change `window.location="member.html"` to `document.write("Password Correct!")`, it worked correctly.

Please help.

Comment: Dude, you really don't want passwords in your source code and handled by JavaScript...

Comment: @Utkanos maybe he's a beginner and only wants to test things out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cancel the click action so the form does not submit

```
onclick="checkPassword(this.form.loginname.value,this.form.loginpwd.value); return false;"
```

I hope you realize this is NOT secure.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of error in code

a) onclick of submit button doesn't return anything hence the form is submitted each time

b) use window.location.href

```
<script>
function checkPassword(name, pwd) {
    if (name == "jamie") {
        if (pwd == "198237645") {
            window.location.href = "memeber.html"
        } else {
            document.write("Wrong Password!")
        }
    } else {
        document.write("Wrong Name!")
    }
    return false;
}
</script>

<form action="" >
  Login Name : <input type="text" name="loginname"><br>
  Login Pwd : <input type="password" name="loginpwd"><br>
  <input type="submit"  onclick = "return checkPassword(this.form.loginname.value,this.form.loginpwd.value)" value="Login">
</form>
```